# github pull request line colors

Tags: github, pull-request, change-tracking

The offending "change" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAsBp.png)

I understand that a red line is supposed to be a deletion and a green line is supposed to be an insertion.  As far as I can tell I didn't actually touch this line. There are no changes to spaces, indentation, etc. in the code.  My team lead is giving me static for tracking white space changes (this is but one of many that showed up in this PR) and I'm rather confused.

Comment: This definitely looks like there was whitespace on that line, and it's been removed. Could be an automatic removal by your editor?

Comment: I'll take a look at my Atom settings and compare with the production code.  Thanks!

Comment: Turns out my lead is NOT using the Atom whitespace manager, but I have been.  Mischief managed (well, for the future).  I would gladly upvote your response @GregSchmidt if I were able